# Incrementing a Date to the next occurence of a pre-defined day of the month

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I've got an application, where I'm asking the user to pick one of 2 days in a month. The 4th or the 18th. When the user has selected this value, I take that value, as-well as today's date.

Before I do any processing, I need to add 25 days for admin work.

```
day = parseInt(day);
var curDateTime = new Date().getTime(),
timeToAdd = (1000*60*60*24*25),
datePlusDays = new Date(),
finalDate = new Date();

datePlusDays.setTime(timeToAdd + curDateTime);

function incrementToSelected(toIncrement, incrementTo){
    var currentDay = parseInt(toIncrement.getDate());

    if (currentDay != incrementTo){
        var addedDay = new Date();
        addedDay.setTime(toIncrement.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24));
        incrementToSelected(addedDay, incrementTo );
    } else if (currentDay === incrementTo){
        finalDate = toIncrement;
    }
}

incrementToSelected(datePlusDays, day);
```

datePlusDays is now today's date + 25 days. Now, I need to find the next occurrence of the date that the user chose.

Currently, I'm using the method above to add one day (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) to the date and check if that is the next occurrence, if it isn't add another, if it is set finalDate with the date.

This does work, but in some cases I'm getting a Maximum call stack size exceeded error. Is there any other way to find the next occurrence of a date?

Comment: I assume you want this to loop over to the next month?  E.g. if I'm on May 16, and incrementTo is 3, you want me to return June 3?

Comment: Yes, but first I need to add 25 days to the date to allow for admin, this is to process direct debits, so I 'incrementTo = 3' then the date I'd need return would be July 3, as June 3 would fall within the 25 day process length.

Comment: Ok, got a solution for you below.  Try it out and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to mess with timestamps.  This will do what you want.  It sets the day to "incrementTo", and conditionally increments the month (if incrementTo is <= the current day of month) and year if necessary (if month is December, rolls over to January and increments the year).

```
function incrementToSelected(toIncrement, incrementTo){
    if (toIncrement.getDate() >= incrementTo) {
        toIncrement.setDate(1); // Avoid month-rollover edge case
        var m = toIncrement.getMonth();
        if (m == 11) {
            toIncrement.setFullYear(toIncrement.getFullYear()+1);
            toIncrement.setMonth(0);
        } else {
            toIncrement.setMonth(m + 1);
        }
    }
    toIncrement.setDate(incrementTo);
}
```

Comment: Actually, Andrew, I just thought of an edge case that will break this.  If your `toIncrement` value is January 31, and your `incrementTo` is 3, it will attempt to incrememnt the month to February 31, which will instead skip to March 3 because Feb has only 28 days.  That's pretty bad.  Will edit with a fix right now.

Comment: Actually all the complications to avoid rollover are unnecessary, they are automatically applied by the data functions. So if `now = new Date ();` to add 25 days just say `now.setDate (now.getDate () + 25)` month and year will automagically roll over as you would want them to.

Comment: @HBP - Yeah, that would work, except he doesn't want to just increment the date, he wants to go to the next instance of a given date in the appropriate month (current or next month, depending on what the current date is)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler using the fact that the Date functions automatically roll over months and years....

```
function Dday (admin, day) {
  var nextDate = new Date();
  nextDate.setDate (nextDate.getDate () + (admin || 25)); // add on the 25 days

  // Caution if day is not within range 1-31 this loop is infinite!
  while (nextDate.getDate () != (day || 4)) // keep adding 1 day till date == day.
    nextDate.setDate (nextDate.getDate () + 1);

  return nextDate;
}
```

I've made the function take two optional parameters, `admin` is the number of admin days defaults to 25 and `day` is the day in the month, defaults to 4.

Answer (score -1):

I've taken what Steven contributed, and have now got the following method to work.

I've removed the need for a function within this method, I was over complicating it when really it's a fairly simple technique.

```
day = parseInt(day);
var curDateTime = new Date().getTime(),
    timeToAdd = (1000*60*60*24*25),
    datePlusDays = new Date(timeToAdd + curDateTime);

if (day >= datePlusDays.getDate()){
    datePlusDays.setDate(day);
} else if (day < datePlusDays.getDate()){
    var m = datePlusDays.getMonth();
    if (m == 11){
        datePlusDays.setFullYear(datePlusDays.getFullYear() + 1);
        datePlusDays.setMonth(0);
    } else {
        datePlusDays.setMonth(datePlusDays.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    datePlusDays.setDate(day);
}

return datePlusDays;
```